# Using regex to trim trailing white space

Tags: regex, editpad

My editor `EditpadPro` allows me to create syntax colouring schemes.
The scheme I'm writing includes comments which span **"--"** to end of a line.

I'd like a regex which starts from the **"--"** but which stops at the last non-blank character. I cannot use "replace" as I'm just entering the regex, not using it myself.

So, if the text in my line of code is:

```
X=1 -- This is a comment with trailing blanks
```

Then the regex would return:

```
-- This is a comment with trailing blanks
```

The reason for this is that I can highlight the trailing blank space as waste space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with EditPad Pro, but

```
--(?:.*\S)?
```

might work.

The idea is to match `--`, followed by 0 or more of any (non-newline) character (`.`), followed by a non-space character (`\S`). Because the "0 or more" part is greedy, it will try to match as much of the line as possible, thus making `\S` match the last non-blank character of the line.

The `?` makes the whole thing after `--` optional. This is because you might have a comment without a non-space character in it:

```
--
```

This should still be matched as a comment, but not any trailing spaces (if any).

Comment: I don't see why it should be downvoted - it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm struggling to understand the `(?:.*\S)` portion of the first one. It's a lookahead, isn't it? But not one I've come across before. I don't recognise the `:` character's function.
The second one's explanation made it easy, even for me. But I'd never fit that explanation into the Syntax Coloring Scheme Editor's comment box for the element!

Comment: @Swifty: No, it's a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). It groups the `.*\S` into a single token which is made optional in its entirety by the `?` following it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of non-capturing group. I searched for `regex (?:` last night, and the very first hit said that a novice might confuse this for lookahead.  Put's me in my place, then.

Answer (score 0):

In the Syntax Coloring Scheme Editor, use the following regex, making sure that the "Dot all" checkbox is unchecked:

```
--.*?(?=[^\r\n\S]*$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
--           # Match --
.*?          # Match any number of non-linebreak characters, as few as possible,
(?=          # until the following can be matched from the current position:
 [^\r\n\S]*  # Any number of whitespace characters except newlines
 $           # followed by the end of the line.
)            # End of lookahead
```

`[^\S]` is the same as `\s`, but the negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) allows you to exclude certain characters from the class of allowed whitespace characters - in this case, newlines.

Comment: I'm also curious. I downvoted sGeeK's "answer", but apparently someone downvoted both of ours, too (in retaliation?).